# ¿Por qué algo inevitable o indiscutible es "impepinable"?

Tags: coloquialismos

¿Por qué cuando algo es inevitable, indiscutible o sabemos que sucederá a ciencia cierta decimos (de manera coloquial) que es `impepinable`?

> Si quieres que te den el carnet de conducir tienes que aprobar tanto el teórico como el práctico. Eso es *impepinable*. No te vale solo con aprobar uno.
>
> Lo de Fulano es un caso *impepinable* de corrupción. Tienen todas esas grabaciones y los testigos.
>
> Que tu equipo iba a ganar era *impepinable*, son un equipo de primera división jugando contra unos de tercera...

En [el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L2qnrJf):

> impepinable
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Cierto, seguro, que no admite discusión.

¿Es esta una de esas expresiones que se forma "de casualidad" y principalmente debido a su sonoridad? ¿O hay un origen conocido y medianamente racional para esta expresión?

Comment: Esta pregunta tal vez necesite una etiqueta de region. Yo nunca he oído eso por aquí.

Comment: Parece que en Argentina no es muy común y sorprendió su uso por parte del presidente: [¿Qué dice Macri cuando dice "impepinable"?](http://www.clarin.com/politica/dice-macri-impepinable_0_4ycfEBU0e.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rebuscando entre las [ocurrencias del CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=impepinable&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) veo una de 1944, de *El idioma como instrumento y el diccionario como símbolo*, de Julio Casares, que propone que es una deformación jocosa de *inopinable*. Es decir, que no admite opinión alguna.

También en el [fichero general](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/fichero-general) hay [una ficha (PDF)](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_I/LETRA_I_PDF/IMPEPINABLE/00001464.pdf) que dice que es originaria del mundo de la farándula, de locutores y artistas, junto con otras como *[impajaritable](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L1cW0Tn)*, de significado similar pero de uso en Chile y Ecuador.

Buscando en la [hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=impepinable&f=text&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&s=0&lang=es) encuentro que la primera aparición de la expresión es de 1889:

> Si Pérez suelta un bastito
>   pequeño, ¿qué hace González?
>   Fallar. Mato con la espada.
>   Doy enseguida un arrastre.
>   Me asiste con el caballo,
>   se desarma, y ¿de qué sale?
>   Tiene que salir de copas...
>   ¡Pues codillo impepinable!
>            - Un tresillista.

Un tresillista es aquel que juega al [tresillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=abDVbLh): juego de naipes que se practica entre tres personas, cada una de las cuales recibe nueve cartas, y que gana en cada lance la que hace mayor número de bazas. Hay [un artículo](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004867310&page=2&search=impepinable&lang=es) de 1899 que dice que los tresillistas tenían su propio argot:

> El tresillo tiene su *argot*. Las cartas sin valor para el juego que se hace reciben los nombres de *podridas*, *cartulinas* y *cucos*. La espada, la mala y
>   punto son *la perla*; el basto y un caballo, *la tenaza*; una sota es *una niña*; el tres de bastos, *Calomarde* y *el atado por los ríñones*. Un solo imperdible se llama *impepinable*.

Lo que ya resulta difícil de decir es si la palabra *impepinable* se originó en este *argot* (es posible, ya que su primer uso aparece en este contexto), si tiene algo que ver con el significado actual, o si fue tomada del contexto farandulero mencionado anteriormente.

Comment: _impajaritable_ si fue usada en Colombia. Las generaciones de los 40 y antes la usaban... ahora ya no es muy común.

Comment: @DGaleano y el diccionario de americanismos [lo recoge](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=DBJCVIbgWx0ApN8fMom), mencionando que también en España se dice. Yo nunca lo he oído.

Comment: @fedorqui ni yo tampoco, la verdad.